# Comprehension help required

Tags: homework, gre

I was given the following question for comprehension pasted below:

> What does John mean when he says that he would only win his own money?

And I answered that John meant that Marry won't be betting any money, so he will be winning only his own money. Professor marked it incorrect. Can you please what exactly is the problem?

I have marked the relevant information in bold letters in the comprehension passage.

> "Hullo," said John, "it's raining again. What a nuisance I Now we
>   shan't be able to play tennis this afternoon."
>
> "No," said Mary, "I suppose we shan't. Let's stay at home and stick
>   some photographs in our book, shall we?"
>
> "Do you really want to?" said John rather doubt. fully. "I thought you
>   said you didn't like doing it because it was so messy."
>
> "Oh,' replied Mary, "I'll just watch you sticking them in."
>
> "Oh, no, you won't," said John. "You've done that to me before. You'll
>   have to do your share, my girl I " "All right. Then what about playing
>   cards? You're keen enough on doing that with your friends at the
>   club."
>
> "But you don't know how to play," protested John. "That's all right.
>   You can teach me, can't you? You taught me to drive a car."
>
> "Well, it's not much fun teaching someone to play cards. The whole
>   point of playing cards is the chance of winning."
>
> "You'd be sure to win if you played with me, because I don't know how
>   to play. Surely that would be better than playing with your friends,
>   because you sometimes lose there."
>
> **"But if I did win when I was playing against you, I would only win my
>   own money."**
>
> Mary laughed. Then she said. "All right, I think we'll just have to go
>   to the cinema. There's a good film on at the Grand, isn't there?"
>
> "Not the Grand," said John. "The Splendid."
>
> "Oh, yes," said Mary. "I keep on getting them mixed up. The Grand's
>   the one down by the river, isn't it?"
>
> "Yes," answered John. "After we've been here a few more weeks we'll
>   know everything there is to know about this town: it's small enough.
>   Well, we'd better go, or we'll be too late for the matinee. Have you
>   got your umbrella back from Jane yet, or will you have to go on
>   sharing mine?"
>
> "No, I got mine back. I came across Jane in a shop this morning. She
>   was carrying my umbrella, but she put it down for a moment while she
>   looked in her handbag for some money. So I picked the umbrella up and
>   started to walk out. The shopkeeper was horrified. He said, 'Madam,
>   that umbrella belongs to this lady!' 'No, it doesn't,' I answered, 'it
>   belongs to me.' 'That's right,' said Jane. 'It does.' You should have
>   seen the shopkeeper's face! He didn't know whether to believe his eyes
>   or his ears-especially as Jane pretended never to have seen me before:
>   you know how she loves a joke!"

Comment: She will be betting their joint money, so he will win his own money  back. This question is off topic at EL&U - perhaps http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: From which book this paragraph is taken??

Answer (score 1):

There are three common uses for this phrase but all have a similar meanings. The extended example you post doesn't really make the phrase clear through context so it isn't much help.

---

The first usage is one where someone gives another person money to use as a loan or gift and then wins the money back later in a contest. While they did win the money, it doesn't really feel like winning because they only walk away with what they already had when they came in. This is the most likely usage to match the example you gave.

> Alice: Can I borrow $5? I want to play some cards with you.
>
> Bob: Sure... but then I'll just be winning my own money. What's in it for me?

---

A second usage is when you win *back* money that you lost in a previous game. A classic example of this is the final scene in the poker movie Rounders. The hero is playing a game against The Russian who won thousands of dollars from him early in the movie. During this scene, the hero beats The Russian and is happy with his winnings. The Russian goads him into playing *another* game by saying, "After all, I am paying you with your money."

---

The third usage is when you *steal* someone's money and then use it to gamble against them. A classic example of this is when someone steals their enemy's wallet and uses the cash found in the wallet to enter a poker game. If they "lose" their enemy will simply be "winning their own money"; the point of this trick is that they can gamble without much risk. Even if they lose, they aren't losing their own money.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like John and Mary might be a married couple and the language suggests an old-fashioned setting. So in this context I may be inclined to assume that John is the bread-winner and he simply means that all of Mary's money comes from him anyway. Alternatively (in a less old-fashioned setting or without the sexist assumptions), they both consider their money their own already. This is supported by how he emphasizes he would be winning his own money when "playing against **you**". This suggests to me that the reason he would consider the money his own is specifically because it would be Mary that he was playing against.